# Parallelize receivers across machines in Spark Streaming

Tags: apache-kafka, spark-streaming, amazon-kinesis

In a Spark streaming app, can I parallelize receivers on all machines in the cluster (and not just a Master)? That way, all nodes in the Spark cluster are reading from an external stream simultaneously.

Answer (score 1):

When deployed on a cluster,  Spark Streaming will use as many cores as specified in `spark.cores.max`. We can programmatically create `n` receivers and they will be spread over the cores reserved for this job, but there is no warranty of an even spread over physical nodes.

As an example using kafka, here we create `kafkaParallelism` receivers.

```
@transient val inKafkaList:List[DStream[(K,V)]] =     List.fill(kafkaParallelism) {
KafkaUtils.createStream[K, V, KDecoder, VDecoder](ssc, kafkaConfig,  topics, StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER)
}
@transient val inKafka = ssc.union(inKafkaList)
```

Note that it's a good practice to union the resulting Dstreams to reduce the number of tasks generated.

Comment: Thanks for your response. When you say no warranty of an even spread over physical machines, are you implicitly acknowledging that Spark will indeed put the receivers on different nodes but there's no guarantee that the distribution will be even? Or is it still a question if the receivers will ever be put on different nodes?

Comment: @RanjitIyer Imagine you create 3 receivers, you assign 8 cores for the streaming job and you have a cluster of 3 machines x 8 cores. Then the possible receiver allocations will be: `(1,1,1), (2,1,0), (3,0,0)` and its permutations. The first case is ideal, as we have 1 receiver per node. In the worst case, illustrated by the last tuple,  all receivers are in 1 physical node. So there's no hard warranty, only a 'soft' one - AFAIK and based on my experience with Mesos clustering. Standalone and YARN might differ.

Comment: thanks so much! I'll run some experiments on YARN. Don't meant to sneak another quesiton but have you tried custom partitioning on DStreams? I've used the JavaPairRDD.partitionBy(Partiotioner) in a batch application but haven't found an equivalent on the JavaDStreamPairRDD. (only seen the 'groupBy(Partiotioner)). I'll post a separate question, but wanted to check if you know something off the top..